# Установить заголовок сервера 204

Tags: node.js, express

Подскажите как осуществить задумку.
В общем, есть каталоги (страницы) с пустым содержанием (временно). Нужно отдать заголовок не 200, а скажем 204 (нет содержимого)

Пишу следующее:

```
if( ! content.length) res.status(204);
res.render("catalog", {
    content: content,
    title: catalog.name,
});
```

Статус то прописывается, но вот на саму страницу не заходит, как я понял до рендера дело не доходит, как решить задачку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Браузер не будет ничего рендерить при коде 204. И это абсолютно правильное поведение, написано же - нет контента

Comment: как быть тогда? не 200 же отдавать если в каталоге нет ничего. На 404 посылать не хочется.
302 отдал, все норм =)

Comment: Вернуть 200 вполне корректно. 

Вообще, если у вас не api а вы возвращаете html, то не стоит увлекаться кодами. Браузеры могут по разному и не желательно реагировать на коды, отличные от 200 и 404